# Ssrs exceed parameter beyond 12000 values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm relatively new to **SSRS** and the use of **tSQL**.  I know there is a limit and performance issue using the `IN` clause but there is a alternative I can use which is a `Join`.  Okay my question is if I were to bring 12000 list of distinct values into a `table` to `join`,  how can I use **SSRS** to `join` into that `table` with using a `parameter`.

I have tried the join on from

```
table1 
Inner join table2 on column = @promptcolumnlist
```

Where `table2` is the list of `12000` values

Can anyone shed some light please.  Sorry if the question was already mentioned somewhere couldn't find the answer i was looking for.

Comment: can you give the sample data. generally it is better to use a stored_procedure inside the dataset for ssrs report. in the stored procedure you should acquire the desired result from multiple tables.

Comment: another thing you can do is, pass the column list as a table value parameter and join it with your tables